# Why does VBA Case Select ignore matches and always default to case else

Tags: excel, vba

Why does it just skip through and not recognize that myslice="Lafarge"
when you can even see below in the watch window that it is true?

[image]

I am trying to set chart colors based on company names.
The Select Case statement never correctly identifies the name and ends up
taking the case else option

code below in case the image does not work

```
Function GetSliceColor(sliceName As String) As Long
    ' Assign a color to the slice based on its name
    Dim myslice As String
    myslice = sliceName
    If sliceName = "Lafarge" Then
    GetSliceColor = RGB(51, 153, 51) ' Green
    End If
    Select Case myslice
        Case "Lafarge"
            GetSliceColor = RGB(51, 153, 51) ' Green
        Case "Heidelberg"
            GetSliceColor = RGB(150, 150, 150)
    

        Case Else
            GetSliceColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' White
    End Select
End Function




EDIT----  If i do this it works
 

    pos = InStr(myslice, "Lafarge")
    
    If pos > 0 Then
     GetSliceColor = RGB(51, 153, 51) ' Green
    End If
```

Comment: because `myslice="Lafarge "` (space added). Try to use `Select Case Trim(myslice)`

Comment: I suspect after see the above response you'll be slapping your forehead (given the answer was staring at you in the Watch window. Maybe take a little more time in your testing before posting?

Comment: trim didn't work, its not that.  I'm going with the InStr function, ugly but it works